# Running FreeBSD wth QEMU on macOS: system gets very slow a few seconds after the start

Tags: freebsd, qemu

I am running the FreeBSD image using QEMU.

When I start it with QEMU it works smoothly for a few seconds, but then the FreeBSD system starts being very slow to respond to my keystrokes. Sometimes this happens a few seconds after the FreeBSD has loaded and I have logged in the system using as a root and sometimes it is already slow when it shows the user/password lines.

What is interesting though is that when I open a second terminal session and connect to the slowly running FreeBSD via SSH (I have set up the sshd in the FreeBSD), the connection seems to work without any issues. Also if I do a verbose command such as `find /` in the QEMU's terminal session it stops being slow for a short while after I stop the command, and then it goes back to being slow again.

It is the first time I am trying QEMU so my guess that the problem is around `-serial mon:stdio` line but it is just a guess.

This is the command I am using:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -m 8192 \
    --bios $(OVMF_LOCATION) \
    -serial mon:stdio \
    -net nic \
    -net user,hostfwd=tcp::10022-:22 \
    freebsd.img
```

The background: I am following the RTEMS OS setup instructions for running it on the QEMU AMD64: [Board Support Package: amd64](https://docs.rtems.org/branches/master/user/bsps/bsps-x86_64.html).

Comment: To the person who is voting for closing this: please let me know how I could improve the question instead of bringing it down. This is a real problem and I am on it, happy to change the wording or provide any missing details.

Comment: I haven't tried qemu, but for testing custom images (https://fabrik.red/post/test/) I successfully have been using VirtualBox/VMware fusion, however probably https://serverfault.com, is a better place for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was suspicious about the `-serial mon:stdio` part of my original command so I looked around to see what else do people try. I found that I have to replace this line with `-nographic` and it starts working without being slow.

This is how my command looks now:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -m 8192 \
    --bios $(OVMF_LOCATION) \
    -nographic \
    -no-reboot \
    -net nic \
    -net user,hostfwd=tcp::10022-:22 \
    freebsd.img
```